# Gulp 4.0 : AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: build-externs

Tags: gulp

I get this error in the follwoing function block

```
function repeatTaskForAllLocales(taskName, dependencies, operation) {
  const tasks = [];
  ALL_LOCALES.forEach((locale) => {
    // Convert build-js-$ to build-js-fr, for example.
    const replaceTokens = (name) => name.replace(/\$/g, locale);

    const localeTaskName = replaceTokens(taskName);
    tasks.push(localeTaskName);
    const localeDependencies = dependencies.map(replaceTokens);
    // old version : gulp.task(localeTaskName, localeDependencies, () => operation(locale));  updated to following line
    gulp.task(localeTaskName, gulp.series(localeDependencies, () => operation(locale))) . // <--- gulpfile.babel.js:177:36
  });
  return tasks;
}
```

wgat could be wrong with the gulp.series() . ?